# how to update multiple "Alternateemailaddress1" field of Nprinting using Nprinting API

Tags: rest, qliksense

I am trying to modify various Nprinting Fields using Nprinting API by writing scipts in Qlik Sense App load script editor.
While most of the fields are updated. Only "Alternateemailaddress1" is not getting updated

API code written in Qlik Sense app

```
    Set s_user_body = '{"Username":$(s_user_name)
                       ,"Email":$(s_user_email)
                       ,"Password":"123"
                       ,"Enabled":"true"
                       ,"Subfolder":""
                       ,"DomainAccount":""
                       ,"Timezone":"Japan"
                       ,"Locale":"ja"
                       ,"Folder":"test1,test2"
                       ,"alternateEmail1":"user1@gmail.com;user2@gmail.com" //ERROR
                       ,"alternateEmail2":"user2@gmail.com"
                       ,"alternateEmail3":"user2@gmail.com"
                       }';
    Let s_user_body = Replace(s_user_body,'"',chr(34)&chr(34));
    Let sPostUserULR = 'https://$(vHostName):port/api/v1/users/'&'$(s_user_id)';

    NoConcatenate
    RestPostUserMasterTable:
        SQL SELECT
                "__KEY_data"
            FROM JSON (wrap off) "data" PK "__KEY_data"
            WITH CONNECTION(URL "$(sPostUserULR)"
                                ,BODY "$(s_user_body)"
                                ,HTTPHEADER "Content-Type" "application/json"
                                ,HTTPHEADER "X-HTTP-Method-Override" "PUT"
                                ,HTTPHEADER "cookie" "$(vCookie)");

    NoConcatenate
    [post_and_put_items]:
    Load
        [__KEY_data] AS [__KEY_data]
    Resident RestPostUserMasterTable
    WHERE NOT IsNull([__KEY_data]);

    Drop table RestGetUserMasterTable;
    Drop table RestPostUserMasterTable;
```

The line "alternateEmail1":"user1@gmail.com;user2@gmail.com" is throwing error
can someone suggest correct method of setting this pattern.